# How to count number of digits in an integer (or letters in a word) and then retrieve any of those digits (or letters)?

Tags: macros

I need to (1) count digits in a number (or count letters in a word), and (2) retrieve any one of those digits (or any one of those letters). Also, there are conditions to be met: `expl3` should not be used as well as packages not authored/maintained by LaTeX Team.

```
\def\zCountDigits#1%
  {% COUNT DIGITS OF #1
  }
\def\zGetDigit#1#2%
  {% GET DIGIT OF #1 AT INDEX #2
  }
```

Comment: I understand that you don't want to pull in `expl3` for that, but what's the point of not using packages not maintained by the LaTeX team? For example, `xstring` provides both `\StrLen` for the length of a string and `\StrChar` to get the n-th character.

Comment: `expl3` _is_ maintained by the LaTeX Team. `expl3` is just a (really, really large) bunch of TeX macros written with a funny catcode setting. The macros you want are `\tl_count:n` and `\tl_item:nn` (or `\str...`): you can always copy them and remove the `_` and `:`. Will it or will it not be `expl3` code then? Your requirements seem a bit pointless to me...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I wholeheartedly understand anyone who doesn't want to learn what is (or at least looks like) essentially a new language to solve some LaTeX problem. (Also, `expl3` _should not be used as well as packages not authored/maintained by LaTeX Team_ sounds like OP is perfectly aware that `expl3` is maintained by the LaTeX team.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can always take existing code and re-work. Here, I've used some ideas from `expl3` but slightly simplified (at the cost of a little robustness)

```
\def\zCountDigits#1{%
  \number\numexpr0\zCountDigitsAux#1\zCountDigitsEnd\relax
}
\def\zCountDigitsAux#1{%
  \ifx\zCountDigitsEnd#1\else+1\expandafter\zCountDigitsAux\fi
}
\def\zCountDigitsEnd{\zCountDigitsEnd}

\zCountDigits{}
\zCountDigits{123}
\zCountDigits{abC}

\def\zGetDigit#1#2{%
  \zGetDigitLoop{1}{#2}#1\zGetDigitEnd
}
\def\zGetDigitLoop#1#2#3{%
  \ifx\zGetDigitEnd#3\else
    \ifnum #1 = #2 %
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zGetDigitCleanup
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#3%
    \else
      \zGetDigitLoopStep{#1}{#2}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\zGetDigitCleanup#1#2\zGetDigitEnd{#1}
\def\zGetDigitLoopStep#1#2\fi\fi{\fi\fi
  \expandafter\zGetDigitLoop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1 + 1\relax}{#2}%
}
\def\zGetDigitEnd{\zGetDigitEnd}

\zGetDigit{abc}{1}
\zGetDigit{abc}{3}
\zGetDigit{abc}{4}
\zGetDigit{abc}{-2}

\bye
```

(I'm not 100% from the spec on whether you want space handling, brace groups preserved, *etc.*: I've gone for the simple approach, but they could be included).

---

The way that the loop works is that `\zCountDigitsAux` grabs one token at a time: if you look at the set up, there are no braces around `#1` in `\zCountDigits`. Thus `\ifx\zCountDigitsEnd#1` is comparing exactly one token to the end marker. 
I've used a private 'end of loop' token rather than say `\relax`. That's to ensure that we can still count an input sequence that includes `\relax`: the counting approach here is valid not only for character tokens but also macros, `\chardef` tokens, *etc.*

Assuming the loop has not finished, we insert `+1` then need to close the conditional. The `\zCountDigitsAux` macro needs to see what is next in the input stream, and we need to avoid opening more and more conditional levels. Hence I use
`\expandafter\zCountDigitsAux\fi`. This expands the `\fi`, ending the conditional, before `\zCountDigitsAux` gets expanded. (Without this, `\zCountDigitsAux` would grab the `\fi`, and we'd run out of stack.) There's no parameter passed to `\zCountDigitsAux` here as the rest of the original argument to `\zCountDigits` is still in the input stream.

Comment: @bp2017 See my edit

Comment: @bp2017 Well known trick: it's a 'quark'. If you use say `{}`, you can get a hit against a token with a different name but the same meaning. With the self-definition that can't happen.

Comment: @bp2017 I'm making sure I end the conditionals then deal with `#3`. As I don't know how many tokens it is, I use a delimited argument to 'clear up' the `\fi` then re-insert them. I could use any marker, but as it makes the conditional clearer to read, normally one sticks to the required number of `\fi`.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution uses no packages at all and hence cannot run afoul of the stricture against the use of packages "not authored/maintained by LaTeX Team". (Aside: I have no idea who the members of "LaTeX Team" are -- or even if there is such a thing.)

Since you use `\def` rather than `\newcommand` in your example, I take it that you're interested primarily in a "plain TeX" solution. The code shown below therefore uses LuaTeX, not LuaLaTeX. The code provides two macros, `\zCountChars` and `\zGetChar`. The macros use the "primitive" command `\directlua` and the built-in LuaTeX functions `tex.sprint`, `string.len`, and `string.sub`.

[image]

```
\def\zCountChars#1{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len("#1"))}}
\def\zGetChar#1#2{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.sub("#1",#2,#2))}}

\zCountChars{1066}, \zCountChars{123abc}.

\zGetChar{6789}{2}, \zGetChar{123abc}{-2}.
\bye
```

Note that it's possible to use a negative number as the second argument of `\zGetChar`. In such cases, the counting starts *from the end* of the string/number rather than from the beginning.

Comment: +1: certainly the most efficient way :-) There _is_ a LaTeX Team, and I'm a member of it (so they say :-). And _even so_ OP's requirements are a bit weird...

Comment: @Mico You never looked at the photos of [our heroes](https://www.latex-project.org/about/team/)? ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - Many thanks for this pointer. I knew there was something called the LaTeX Project, but I wasn't aware of the existence of an associated entity called the LaTeX Team. The team members sure look like an all-star cast! And, of course, my thanks to you for volunteering to be a member of this illustrious team.