# Count digits of result of arithmetic operation

Tags: macros

Based on J.Wright's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501669/15542)  I 
wanted to count the characters of an operation. Nevertheless the output of the code below is

> 16 12321 **2**

where instead of the bold number I expected to count the number of characters of the previous `12321`. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\zCountDigits#1{%
  \number\numexpr0\zCountDigitsAux#1\zCountDigitsEnd\relax
}
\def\zCountDigitsAux#1{%
  \ifx\zCountDigitsEnd#1\else+1\expandafter\zCountDigitsAux\fi
}
\def\zCountDigitsEnd{\zCountDigitsEnd}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\eval}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}

% the result of the next is 16, as should
\zCountDigits{0123456789ABCDEF}
% the evaluation gives 12321
\eval{int(111*111)}  
% but the counting the result gives 2, not five
\zCountDigits{\eval{int(111*111)}} 

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual problem: `\eval` is not expandable.

Here's a more straightforward implementation with `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\CountDigits}{m}
 {
  \cp_count_digits:e { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \cp_count_digits:n { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cp_count_digits:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% the result of the next is 16, as it should
\CountDigits{0123456789ABCDEF}
% the evaluation gives 12321
\inteval{111*111}
% the counting of digits in the result gives 5, as it should
\CountDigits{\inteval{111*111}} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

@egreg explained you why your approach fails: your macro is not expandable. There are two options: either you switch gears and use the `expl3` machinery. There is nothing wrong with that. On the other hand, if you use `pgf`, `tikz` and/or `pgfplots` anyway, it is arguably preferable to build these functions into the pgf ecosystem. For many functions, this has been done already, in particular [digitsum is already available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504402/194703). So you could just use it. I actually advise against using a macro but suggest to use the parsing and number printing machinery, but I added a macro, too.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgf}
\makeatletter
\newcount\c@Digits
\newcount\c@Powers
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{digitcount}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
  \global\c@Digits=0%
  \expandafter\DigitCount@i#1\@nil%
  \pgfmathparse{int(\the\c@Digits)}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\def\DigitCount@i#1#2\@nil{%
  \advance\c@Digits by \@ne%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\DigitCount@i#2\@nil\fi%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\DigitCount}[1]{\pgfmathparse{digitcount(int(#1))}\pgfmathresult}
\begin{document}
If you really want a marco: \DigitCount{111*111}

Cross--check: \pgfmathparse{int(111*111)}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult

I'd suggest parsing within the pgf system: \pgfmathparse{digitcount(int(111*111))}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult

Works with strings, too: \pgfmathparse{digitcount("0123456789ABCDEF")}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

[image]