How to get the length of an integer with expl3?
Just like the question above, if I input 31415926, then it will output 8. How to achieve this?

You may want to say "integer" as "integral" is rather old-fashioned and has other meanings. Regardless, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501669/208544

@Teepeemm At some point "integral" (at least as an adjective) was related to "integer". See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element. See also 1(b,1) here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integral

See \tl_count:n, \str_count:n, etc.

Are you expecting also negative integers? If so, what should be the output?

are you assuming valid input? i.e. do you need to distinguish non-integers from integers?

Integer arithmetic in TeX is allowed up to 231 − 1 (in absolute value).
Assuming you want the number of digits (negative integers are stripped of their sign), you can simply count them once you have the representation.
Also counters and arithmetic expressions are allowed.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countdigits}{O{10}m}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #2==0 }
   { 0 }
   { \skyrmion_countdigits:e { \int_to_base:nn { \int_abs:n {#2} } {#1} } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \skyrmion_countdigits:n
 {
  \str_count:n {#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \skyrmion_countdigits:n {e}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}

The number $0$ has \countdigits{0} digits.

The number $12345$ has \countdigits{12345} digits.

The number $000012345$ has \countdigits{000012345} digits.

The number $12345$ has \countdigits[2]{12345} bits.

The number $123-150$ has \countdigits{123-150} digits.

\setcounter{test}{\inteval{12345*54321}}

The number stored in \texttt{test} has \countdigits{\value{test}} digits.

\end{document}

As a bonus I added an optional argument for the radix (from 2 to 36).

Yes, the first line is correct. The integer 0 has no digits in any radix. We just write it with the digit 0 or we couldn't “see” it. It's not different from the third line, where leading zeros are not counted!

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which makes use of Lua's string.len function.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\numdigits[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len(#1))}}
  
\begin{document}
\numdigits{0} 
\numdigits{31415926} 
\numdigits{123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890}
\end{document}

The macro \numdigits is fully expandable, in the TeX-specific sense of the term, because \directlua is fully expandable.  The argument of \numdigits should either be an integer or evaluate to (the functional equivalent of) an integer. Thus, \numdigits{50-49} is fine, as is \numdigits{string.rep(1234567890,60)}. (string.rep is another Lua function; I will let you guess what it does.)

In case there's some uncertainty over what I mean by the "functional equivalent of an integer": 50 (an actual integer) and "50" (a string-based representation of an integer) meet this criterion, but 50.0 does not, as it's a floating point number with a zero decimal component, not an integer. If your use case has you working with floating point numbers with a zero decimal component, I suggest you first convert the floating point numbers to their integer-representation equivalent by, say, running them through Lua's math.floor function.

Here is an attempt that you may consider:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\intlength}{m}
 {
    \fp_eval:n { 
        logb( abs ( trunc ( #1 , 0 ) ) ) + 1
    } 
      
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\numdigits}{m} % without packages
 {
    \fpeval{
        logb( abs ( trunc ( #1 , 0 ) ) ) + 1
    }
 }
\begin{document}

The length of 12345 is: \intlength{12345}

The length of -9876 is: \intlength{-9876}

The length of 7 is: \intlength{7}

The length of 1000000 is: \intlength{1000000}

The length of 12.1 is: \intlength{12.1}

The length of 12345 is: \numdigits{12345}

The length of -9876 is: \numdigits{-9876}

The length of 7 is: \numdigits{7}

The length of 1000000 is: \numdigits{1000000}

The length of 12.1 is: \numdigits{12.1}

\end{document}

This returns the base-10 logarithm of the integer, rounded down. To get the actual number of digits, we need to add 1 to this result.
Note that there are two options given above: one within ExplSyntax and one without.


It's certainly more efficient to use \tl_count:n.  Perhaps first \int_eval:n to make sure there are no leading zeros, and a check for negative numbers or zero.
